# How can i implement such UI pattern?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I have such kind of question.
I use actionBar(Sherlock) with `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`. In portrait mode it works fine. FragmentA on the first screen, information with tabs on another.

In landscape mode on the left side I have ListFragmentA with items, on the right side i have ViewPager with item info separated into few tabs(swiping fragments). (picture A)

How can i implement UI shown on picture B?

What i have (Picture A) [image]

What i want to obtain (Picture B) [image]

Comment: In picture B. You don't want tabs you'll want a ViewPager and a ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use a custom implementation of a ViewPager like the ViewPagerIndicator from Jake Wharton. It's a ViewPager with tabs(and other indicators)
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: @OpCoder The ActionBar tabs occupy the whole width of a screen. The ViewPager tabs on the other hand can be reduced to a certain section of a screen.